# On a question in regards to Ergativity

Tags: grammar, ergativity

I am working on a conlang, and I am making sure of how this one sentence would be parsed when translated.

"We have no friends, but the mountains"

Would mountains be the ones put into the absolutive? Or would it be friends? Due to the way it is separated I can see both arguments, as both are essentially objects of the transitive "have". Would they both be absolutive?

This is less about this one example, and more so a general question of how Ergative Absolutive acts in situations such as these.

Answer (score 3):

To have or any verb expressing possession is not a good verb to demonstrate ergativity, because many language (both nominative/accusative languages and ergative languages) have constructions like this one from Latin:

```
Nobis  non sunt amici       nisi montes.
We_DAT NEG are  friends_NOM except mountains_NOM
```

where the possesor is in the dative case and the possessed is in the nominative case and the subject of the sentence.

But of course, for a conlang you can just define "to have" as a transitive verb and have a construction like this

```
Not friends_ABS but mountains_ABS we_ERG have_3PERS_PL (agreeing with friends and mountains)
```

Comment: Thanks. And in the conlang Not Have is one verb. Like Have-not. And it doesn't have plurals. But that still helps. Thank you.

Comment: BTW, there is [conlang.se] for conlanging, if you don't know that site yet.

Comment: I know, but this was more so a general question on Ergativity alongside a conlang question. I just felt this place might be a bit better when asking about Ergativity. But yeah, could have asked there.

Comment: Don't mind, the two sites have some overlap, and you can choose where to ask the question.

Comment: For the Latin equivalent, *but* here means "except", so *sed* should be *nisi*.

Comment: @TKR: Incorporated *nisi* into the example